# Subgrid in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have my subgrid fields editable. Now on tabout of the fields i am saving the values. 
How can i refresh the expanded subgrid,(without clicking on + icon again)once my fields are saved.

I have a grid: commandgrid, which is the main grid.

For subgrid please find the below code

```
         subGrid: true,
           subGridUrl : "subgriddata.htm?subgridType=vendor",
           gridView: true,
           subGridModel: [ {
           name:  ['Contact Person','Tax ID','Address','Phone Number','Fax Number','Email','City','State','Delete','Add New Contact',''],
           width : [200,150,200,200,150,200,200,200,50,50,2],
           params: ['VENDOR_ID'] }
        ]
```

Comment: The only method i found out was a workaround for the same involving calling the toggle by using the following code : 

     `$("#mygrid").expandSubGridRow(rowid);`
      `$("#mygrid").toggleSubGridRow(rowid);`

This essentially uses the same logic behind the + icon sign

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong. toggleSubGridRow will toggle between + and - icons. i.e. If grid is expanded it will close it and if it is collapsed it expands the grid.In my case the subgrid is already expanded  and now without closing it i want the subgrid to be refreshed, without clicking on '+' icon for that row.